# Sort Map by Defined Order of Keys in Groovy

Tags: sorting, groovy, hashmap

I have a configuration file to specify fields to extract from a JSON document, which I then want to write to a CSV file.

At the moment, I am iterating through the JSON document and assigning the specified keys and values to a `HashMap<String,Object>`, and then adding those to an `ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>`. It seems that the map is populated as the information is read from the JSON document.

How can I sort my maps to be in the order of the fields specified in the configuration file? I've searched online but only found examples on how to sort alphabetically or numerically which is not what I want.

Configuration: `"useFields":["id","created","subject","status","priority"]`

Current output: `["created:16-Feb-2017, id:1234, priority:low, status:Foo, subject:Bar"]`

Desired output: `["id:1234, created:16-Feb-2017, subject:Bar, status:Foo, priority:low"]`

Comment: Instead of a HashMap, take a look at ListOrderedMap from common-collections: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/ListOrderedMap.html

Comment: Thanks. So I assume I should iterate through my configured fields, grab the content from the JSON using that key, and then add it to the ListOrderedMap?  I'll give that a shot!

Comment: The standard Java `LinkedHashMap` provides the same functionality, AND it is the class used by map literals in Groovy. try the same thing as you suggested above but just start the second map with `[:]`. It should order the keys exactly as inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Java class `LinkedHashMap` sorts map entries in the order they were added. And, as it turns out, the actual object created when you use the Groovy "map literal" syntax is, in fact, `LinkedHashMap`. So, getting the effect you want is as simple as creating an empty map literal and adding the entries from the existing map in the order desired:

```
final useFields = ["id","created","subject","status","priority"]

def input = [created:"16-Feb-2017", id:1234, priority:"low", status:"Foo", subject:"Bar"]
println input

def output = [:]
useFields.each { output[it] = input[it] }
// or this one-liner:
// def output = useFields.inject([:]) { out, key -> out[key] = input[key]; out }
println output
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This works as you've described, although I think I've found a more memory efficient way to achieve what I'm after at a later point in my program where I don't have to create multiple map instances.